Can I present the results of my published article at a conference if another author previously presented it?
I am considering presenting a paper I coauthored (with equal contribution) and am corresponding author at an upcoming conference. The paper has already been published, but theresults were presented by another coauthor at a conference before the publication.
I would like to know:

Is it acceptable to present the published work again at a conference?

Should I take consent or inform other coauthors before proceeding, or
is this typically understood to be permissible if I clearly mention
all information like joint work, publication and presentation?


I want to ensure there are no ethical concerns or misunderstandings
when presenting our work. Any advice or experiences on this matter
would be greatly appreciated.

I think you need to provide more information about it. What is your field? Are these two conferences in the same field? Usually, it is frowned upon to present work from another conference; you should only present the findings of your current submission and use other publications as a comparison or motivation to your current work.

My area of research is Mathematics. Previously the results are presented in the confrence which focuses on algebra, analysis, and now the Conference is related to borader area of mathematics with artificial intelligence.

In my experience this is done all the time in pure maths. Sometimes it also happens that the same person is presenting the same results at multiple different conferences.

Actually, I am scared because of my advisor's misguidance. One time, he told me there would be no problem with presenting, but when I was ready, he blocked it say that it will not create any problem when you have to include it in your thesis. Now he is claiming that I have not presented it any conference yet

Do you have more recent results that haven't been published or presented?

Yes sir. For other set of matrices I have obtained new results which aligns with previous published results.

To go through you questions one-by-one:

Is it acceptable to present the published work again at a conference?

It depends upon the specific context and norms of your field. In my field, the life sciences, this is typically okay as long as it is not the same meeting and there are different target audiences. In fact, sometimes, coauthors and I will reuse and share parts of presentations to reach broader audiences. For example, author A might present at the Underwater Basketweaving International Meeting, author B might present at the Basketweaving National Meeting, and author c might present at the State Weaving International Meeting.
Also, if author A presented at the Underwater Basketweaving International Meeting 2023, you should typically should not present at the Underwater Basketweaving International Meeting 2024 unless you have major changes to your results and conclusions.

Should I take consent or inform other coauthors before proceeding, or is this typically understood to be permissible if I clearly mention all information like joint work, publication and presentation?

Yes, open communication with all coauthors is key.
If any disagree, you should not present the work.
Your coauthors will also know the norms and expectations of your field.

I want to ensure there are no ethical concerns or misunderstandings when presenting our work. Any advice or experiences on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

My number one piece of advice would to have open communication with your coauthors.

Actually, I am scared because of my advisor's misguidance. In the initial stage when I opposed that I will present the results then he told me that show your big heart and let your junior to present the work you will not get any trouble when you have to include it in your thesis.But When it's time for my Phd submission he is telling that since you have not presented the results you cannot include in your thesis.  To include it in your thesis you should present it first. Should I only inform or take written consent prior to presentation. Please guide me properly.

Sorry to hear that you're having conflict with your advisor. I think that is actually your bigger problem. Please consider rewording your question to reflect your situation. BTW, there are several questions on this site already about advisor-mentee conflict. Perhaps some of those questions will help your situation.

@Rst Unless math is very different, you need your coauthors' permission to submit an application to present, which they should clearly be an author on.

@AzorAhai-him- maths is very different. In my experience the expectation in maths is that all coauthors are responsible for the whole paper and "own" all the results. Often the "application to present" is submitting an abstract where the coauthors are typically mentioned by "This is joint work with ...".

@Christian You do not need your coauthor's permission to submit an abstract in math? I will leave my comment with the caveat because sometimes people who aren't in math do come to this site.

@AzorAhai-him- No formal permission in any case. And I think that it is expected that everybody is happy when the joint work is advertised. Discussions whether it is okay to present typically happen if coauthors want to present at the same event - so they make sure that they do not talk about the same thing. I always ask my coauthors if they are fine with me presenting joint work but I think it is not something that is universally expected in maths.

@Christian Interesting. At least in my areas, submitting without approval would be a faux pas, although really only an issue if it was a persistent habit.

@AzorAhai-him- I think the key is if there's conference proceedings. In cases where there are none, I've never been asked. In the case there are archival proceedings, then approval is needed like a paper.

@user71659 Ah, good to know. I don't have conference proceedings.

There are two (at least) considerations. The first is what the conference committee permits for such things. Conferences in some fields, and some conferences, perhaps, in many others, will permit such talks as a way of spreading recent results, even if they have been presented or published elsewhere. Others will not, requiring some key "innovation" in presentations. So, ask the committee (or program) chair.
The second consideration is the opinions of your co-authors, but I'd find it hard to think they would be an obstacle, so long as you present it as joint work, listing everyone with an authorship position. Among other things, you should probably point attendees in some fashion, perhaps a slide, to the earlier published and presented work.
EDIT: Given some comments and additions, let me suggest that a better alternative would be to focus any presentation on new results and to name the presentation accordingly. Indicate that the talk is a follow up to the earlier one. This will make attendees and, I hope, your advisor happier.

Yes the conference committee permits. I talked to them they state that write the email we will allow. If I will give the presentation with the aim to promote the work then it's fine or should I add some more work and then present it with new title?

That is your choice, just be sure to give credit so as to avoid any hint of plagiarism.

If I present results that have already been published and presented, what should I do about the title of the presentation? Is it necessary to keep the title the same as the one used for the published article?

I doubt it, but your co-authors might have suggestions, as might the program chair. As long as you have a way to cite the earlier presentations and publications, the title itself is less important. Don't present it as new work, however, unless it is. People might actually be confused if the titles are the same if either presentation is cited in the future.
